# Leer un archivo local con pdf.js

Tags: javascript, cors, jspdf

Tengo problemas para leer el PDF. No me permite leer un archivo local, solo acepta PDF almacenados en la nube.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/2.4.456/pdf.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="the-canvas" height="500" width="500"></canvas>
<script>
    var url = "./plano.pdf"
    var pdf;
    pdfjsLib.getDocument(url).promise.then(doc => {
        pdf = doc;
        render();
    });

    function render() {
        pdf.getPage(1).then(page => {
            var myCanvas = document.getElementById("the-canvas");
            var context = myCanvas.getContext("2d");
            var viewport = page.getViewport({ scale: 1 });
            myCanvas.width = viewport.width;
            myCanvas.height = viewport.height;
            page.render({
                canvasContext: context,
                viewport: viewport
            });
        });
    }

</script>
```

El error que me sale es...

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///C:/Users/xxxxxxxxx/plano.pdf' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, chrome-untrusted, https.

Comment: Estás abriendo el HTML desde su ubicación en disco duro y, por razones de seguridad, el navegador no te permitirá acceder a archivos en el disco. ¿Tienes instalado un servidor web en tu computadora? XAMMP o Wampserver suelen ser buenas opciones.